# In Java why Array's class constructor is private?

Tags: java, arrays

Arrays Class Constructor:-

```
private Arrays() {}
```

My question is that if Array's class constructor is private then how exactly we are creating an object of Arrays.
Then what is the meaning of the below statement:-

```
int[] anArray = new int[10];
```

What is the relationship between the above statement and Array's class.

Any help for the question will be really appriciated.

Comment: The `Arrays`-class is a static helper-class for manipulating arrays, not a "real" array.

Comment: BTW There is also an `Array` helper class. And you can find a number of ArrayUtil and ArrayUtils classes on the web as well. :|

Comment: So you can't construct it. Why? Because that's the way they designed it. It doesn't have any instance methods, so you don't need an instance. Not constructive.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays is simply a utility class for working with arrays, Just like Collections is a utility class for working with, you guessed it, collections. The statement new int[10] is a language construct and has nothing to do with the Arrays class.

Answer (score 2):

`private Arrays() {}`

I guess because all the public utility methods in `java.util.Arrays` are `static` and hence we don't need any instance of this class to use those methods . So designers of the language have decided to keep the constructor of `Arrays` are `private` to restrict instantiation .

`int[] anArray = new int[10];`

That is a java language construct to define an array , a data structure , don't mix this up with `Arrays` which is an utility class in java . For more on

array : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html
`Arrays` : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays` is a utility intended for static usage.
`int[]` is a pseudo-primitive type, which doesn't have a constructor. there isn't a real relationship between those.